# How can I set a filter based on month/year using sumif on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Using google sheets, How could I limit the filter for a given month? Currently I'm trying to build [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18CFIFs5gEXmkGWdpNQXAa9d5xybF7UfO-ZqgdR_lS7c/edit#gid=0) where I want to show the values for every month on a column.

Currently what I have so far is this formula, which matches the category and sums the values correctly, but only the month and year filter are missing since I'm not sure how can I achieve it.

```
=SUMIF(spending!B2:B945;B3;spending!D2:D945)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in D4:

```
     =ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIFS(spending!$D$2:$D$945;spending!$B$2:$B$945;$B4;text(spending!$A$2:$A$945;"mmm");D$2))
```

Use D2:Z2 correctly Type correct name of each month... This should work.. D2 should be `Set` for September

**EDIT:**

Edited to suit locale differences.
Killed various bugs
D2:Z2 should be :
jan
fev
mar
abr
mai
jun
jul
ago
set
out
nov
dez

Comment: Does it work? You need to have a water column in your spending to see this in effect

Comment: what you mean by water column? can you set live example on google docs? Since the given code didn't work.

Comment: D4 contains on the left `Water` . In the spending sheet, you need to add a spend - like `water` from the data validation and some cash out- say 50$. This formula surely works.

Comment: Add a September date in spending A column and check water from the data validation in spending B column and 50$ in `OUT` column